# How to add android C# library (Binding Library) to MAUI android references only

Tags: maui

I have created a .Net C# Android Binding Library. I want to reference that project to only to android references(net6.0-android). When I'm trying to add it is referencing to net6.0, net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, which is not correct as the library is android C# library.
How to add the android C# library to MAUI net6.0-android only.

android library should be referenced to MAUI net6.0-android only.

Comment: When you are creating the library it should only Target Android...

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes, I have created the Library targeting to Android. I want the same library to add as reference to only MAUI project (net6.0-Android) instead it is referencing to net6.0, net6.0-iOS.

Comment: You can watch this official video of MAUI which explains how to bind Android Library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/dotnetconf-focus-on-maui/binding-native-libraries-for-dotnet-maui

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler than it looks, but there is no way (or at least I have not found it) to do it visually or with a wizard.

Just add the reference, then download the project and edit the project file.
Find the `ItemGroup` with the references you want unique to a platform(for example android) and add this:
`<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) != false ">`